# HoltWinters smoothing parameters - alpha = 1 beta = 0 gamma = 0

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, holtwinters

I am trying to use HoltWinters(in R) on the below time series data. As can be seen, it has trend + seasonality. I have 25 monthly data points.

[image]

But on checking the object returned by HoltWinters() function, below is what I get.

[image]

What is causing the alpha, beta, gamma to be at extremes? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks ok to me.

beta=0 means the fitted trend was good for the entire window of data, rather than needing a smooth adjustment from step to step. your graph looks like a good fit to a line after deseasonalization.

alpha=1 says the trend value does not affect the (unobserved) level -- trend is merely an offset to the (observed) y that steadily increases over time, and does not feed back into the system state.

how did you generate this timeseries?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is a monthly plot of one of the KPIs(factual) that I am looking to forecast. I know the data points are few but just wanted to take a stab at it.